# Why using double as input always return 0 as result?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to solve this "mistery":

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PassingVariables {

    double answer, myNumber1, myNumber2; 

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        new PassingVariables();
    }

    public PassingVariables() {
        InputValue1();
        InputValue2();
        calc((double) myNumber1, (double) myNumber2);
    }

    public void InputValue1() {
        BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader (new     InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Type in a number: ");
            myNumber1 = Integer.parseInt(input1.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e){} 
    }

    public void InputValue2() {
        BufferedReader input2 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader  (System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Type in another number");
            myNumber2 = Integer.parseInt(input2.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }

    public double calc(double myNumber1, double myNumber2){
        double answer = ((double)myNumber1 + (double)myNumber2);
        System.out.println("Your number is: " + (double) answer);
        return answer;
    }
}
```

The thing is: this piece of code is not giving me back doubles results, which is exactly what I want.
Every time I put a double, it gives me as a result the value 0.0
But I try to use integers, it gives me as a result something like

1 + 3 = 4.0

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and use Java naming conventions. It really helps people to read and understand your code, and so give help more quickly.

Comment: Sorry, Andy. I'm still learning, I do not even know how should I proper indent my code. Thanks anyway for trying to help me.

Comment: We were all beginners once :) Take a look at how @LuiggiMendoza has done it - at a basic level, indent more when you write `{`, outdent when you write `}`. It's something that comes easily with practice, but it is a very good habit to get into as soon as you can.

Comment: Please don't focus only on the code indentation. More importantly, check the title of the question: by reading it, you get an idea of what to look in the question. And the text moved in the post. Any text for *questions?*, *thanks*, *regards* or similar is noise and doesn't explain your problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza no, of course, but it is a good way to make the code readable so that we can easily get the gist of the code from its structure.

Comment: @AndyTurner indenting code properly is *easy* comparated with the effor to write proper content to the question. That's my point.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'm actually struggling, I'm from Brazil and that is my first question here, so I'm kinda lost. Learning code in another language is harder than you can think. Anyways, I appreciate all your commends and advices. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `Integer.parseInt(input2.readLine());` Try changing both parseInt line to `Double.parseDouble(...)`

**Edit**

here is updated code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PassingVariables {

    double answer, myNumber1, myNumber2; 

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        new PassingVariables();
    }

    public PassingVariables() {
        InputValue1();
        InputValue2();
        calc((double) myNumber1, (double) myNumber2);
    }

    public void InputValue1() {
        BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader (new     InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Type in a number: ");
            myNumber1 = Double.parseDouble(input1.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e){} 
    }

    public void InputValue2() {
        BufferedReader input2 = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader  (System.in));
        try {
            System.out.println("Type in another number");
            myNumber2 = Double.parseDouble(input2.readLine());
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }

    public double calc(double myNumber1, double myNumber2){
        double answer = ((double)myNumber1 + (double)myNumber2);
        System.out.println("Your number is: " + (double) answer);
        return answer;
    }
}
```